# Tag Wiki Edits don't show up with tag guidance is edited?

Tags: support

I noticed that there is a badge for Tag Wiki Edits, but I don't seem to be accumulating any edits towards that badge. Do they not apply when you're editing only the guidance text for the tag?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct.

To earn credits toward the Research Assistant badge you have to edit tag wiki body text, not just the guidance.

This is stated in the badge description but it is easily missed.